# Как избавиться от подтормаживания при смене "тяжелых" фрагментов?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-animation, fragment-transaction

1) Сделал кастомную вьюху с множеством анимаций (10 кругов, которые вращаются вокруг свой оси в разные стороны):

```
public class LogoViewXml extends FrameLayout {

    public LogoViewXml(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LogoViewXml(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        final Animation animationRotateLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                context, R.anim.heart_rotate_left);

        final Animation animationRotateRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                context, R.anim.heart_rotate_right);

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

        ImageView logoMain = new ImageView(context, attrs);
        logoMain.setLayoutParams(params);
        logoMain.setScaleX(0.5f);
        logoMain.setScaleY(0.5f);
        logoMain.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.main_logo));
        this.addView(logoMain);

        ImageView circle1 = new ImageView(context, attrs);
        circle1.setLayoutParams(params);
        circle1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart_anim_01));
        this.addView(circle1);

        ImageView circle2 = new ImageView(context, attrs);
        circle2.setLayoutParams(params);
        circle2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart_anim_02));
        this.addView(circle2);

        ImageView circle3 = new ImageView(context, attrs);
        circle3.setLayoutParams(params);
        circle3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart_anim_03));
        this.addView(circle3);

        ImageView circle4 = new ImageView(context, attrs);
        circle4.setLayoutParams(params);
        circle4.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart_anim_04));
        this.addView(circle4);

        ImageView circle5 = new ImageView(context, attrs);
        circle5.setLayoutParams(params);
        circle5.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart_anim_05));
        this.addView(circle5);

        ImageView circle6 = new ImageView(context, attrs);
        circle6.setLayoutParams(params);
        circle6.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart_anim_06));
        this.addView(circle6);

        ImageView circle7 = new ImageView(context, attrs);
        circle7.setLayoutParams(params);
        circle7.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart_anim_07));
        this.addView(circle7);

        ImageView circle8 = new ImageView(context, attrs);
        circle8.setLayoutParams(params);
        circle8.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart_anim_08));
        this.addView(circle8);

        ImageView circle9 = new ImageView(context, attrs);
        circle9.setLayoutParams(params);
        circle9.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart_anim_09));
        this.addView(circle9);

        ImageView circle10 = new ImageView(context, attrs);
        circle10.setLayoutParams(params);
        circle10.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.heart_anim_10));
        this.addView(circle10);

        /* Start anim */
        circle1.startAnimation(animationRotateRight);
        circle2.startAnimation(animationRotateRight);
        circle3.startAnimation(animationRotateLeft);
        circle4.startAnimation(animationRotateRight);
        circle5.startAnimation(animationRotateRight);
        circle6.startAnimation(animationRotateLeft);
        circle7.startAnimation(animationRotateRight);
        circle8.startAnimation(animationRotateRight);
        circle9.startAnimation(animationRotateRight);
        circle10.startAnimation(animationRotateLeft);
    }
```

2) Также у меня есть некоторое количество фрагментов, которые должны обязательно содержать эту "тяжелую" вьюху и остальные элементы. Добавляю вьюхи таким образом:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".application.entrance.fragments.EntranceFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.proj_name.custom.LogoViewXml
            android:id="@+id/logoView"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/entrance_registration"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/entrance_registration"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/base_btn_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/base_btn_state"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:text="Регистрация"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/entrance_login"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/entrance_login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/base_btn_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/base_btn_state"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:text="Аккаунт"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.551"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

3) Для смены фрагментов использую такой метод:

```
public static void changeFragment(Activity activity, Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_entrance, fragment, tag);
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

4) Моя проблема заключается в том, что при смене фрагментов появляются тормоза (доли секунды задержки загрузки нового фрагмента). Понимаю, что это связано с моей кастомной вьюхой, в которой происходит инициализация и запуск всех анимаций, но я не знаю как это исправить.
Может у вас будут какие то варианты или подсказки к решению данной ситуации? Спасибо.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что круги декоративные? Тогда не делайте их вьюшками, рисуйте их с помощью Canvas в родительском элементе в методе onDraw(). Это должно значительно облегчить жизнь фрагмента. И даже если они кликабельны определить какой был нажат не должно быть проблемой

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий, спасибо за ответ. У меня круги в формате SVG. Конечно, первым делом я начал использовать Canvas, но применяя к каждому элементу Matrix (для rotate моих фигур) и каждый раз вызываяя invalidate, я получал большие тормоза. Затем переделал через SurfaceView, но тормоза так и сохранились. Поэтому решил сделать вот таким способом. В данном случае тормозов практически нет, но появились проблемы с загрузкой вьюхи. Я могу Вам показать код с Канвой?

Comment: Покажите, может что-то смогу подсказать. Еще из вариантов для шустрого отображения и кручения - OpenGL. Если не знакомы с ним придется немного повозиться на первых порах, но зато проблемы с производительностью точно решатся) Еще опишите функциональность и содержание кругов. Почему они в векторные? Там внутри сложные фигуры? Они декор или интерактивные?

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий, 1) OpenGL как раз такие думал начать использовать, если все будет печально. В принципе, разобраться можно будет (да и нужно) 2) SVG привык использовать повсюду (но у меня есть вариант PNG и прочие форматы) 3) По поводу остальных вопросов... Как Вам будет лучше показать что у меня есть? Включая код и ресурсы.

Comment: Если прям весь проект хотите показать - можно залить на гитлаб или гитхаб. Можно просто архивом на файлопомойку. Если не хотите на общее обозрение выкладывать - можно на почту, в профиле указана

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий спасибо большое. В ближайшее время скину Вам на почту.

Answer (score 0):

Можно запускать анимации с задержкой. Открыли фрагмент - подождали несколько сотен милисекунд, пока фрагмент открывается - запустили анимации

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, простым путем тут не решить. Вам нужно решить что делать с вашей кастомной вьюхой.
Решение навскидку - это ленивый и асинхронный inflate вашей вьюхи. Почитайте про AsyncLayoutInflater, возможно, это вам поможет. Решения тут в стиле "напишите код за меня" не будет, увы, потому что вам придется чем-то пожертвовать.
Либо оптимизировать как-то вашу вьюху, либо делать асинхронный inflate, и показывать прогресс, пока ваша вьюха инфлейтится.
Чтобы понять, когда запускать inflate - вам нужно знать когда закончится анимация фрагмента. Можете забить на это, а можете почитать вот тут [костыль](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120372/performing-action-after-fragment-transaction-animation-is-finished/15399035)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Начну с того, что "напишите код за меня" в моем вопросе не звучало! Я просил "варианты и подсказки". 1) С AsyncLayoutInflater, к сожалению, не знаком, но обязательно прочитаю про этот способ. 2) Анимация у меня бесконечна (постараюсь найти пример и добавить в вопрос)